# A numbered list with arbitrary order of items

Tags: lists, theorems, enumerate

Inside a theorem environment I have a numbered list of theorem statements.

Afterward it goes a proof. In the proof I prove every of the above specified numbered statements.

But the order in the proof may be different than the order in the theorem.

Which environment best to use in the proof? I may manually write "1.", "2." or make a definition list with numeric labels, or whatever. Which way is the best?

Comment: You could use a simple `enumerate` and then use `\label` and `\ref`

Comment: I would a bit oppose @cmhughes 's idea: if there're like 3 points in the theorem and not 20, it might be ok _not to use referencing system_ and say directly something like `\begin{description}\item[Proof of claim 3.] blabla \item[Proof of claim 1.] blabla \end{description}`

Comment: @tohecz manually labelling/referring three (or even two) points can result in inconsistencies or in bad numbering if the order of the points is changed for some reason.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina But let's face it: you would (ok, I would) number it as `claim1` to `claim3` because you don't have to bother to think out some names for them. And then if you switch them, you get a complete confusion if you leave the original labels.

Comment: @tohecz I would *never* use that kind of keys for labels; keys must be descriptive and not be tied to an specific numbering.

Answer (score 5):

As  **cmhughes** suggested in his comment, you can use an `enumerate` environment with labelled `\item`s to build the theorem, and then use `\ref` in the proof (this guarantees you consistency and avoids possible errors from manually numbering):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
For a left artin ring $\Lambda$ we have the following.
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{th:radnil} The radical of $\Lambda$ is nilpotent.
\item\label{th:finsim} There is only a finite number of nonisomorphic simple $\Lambda$-modules.
\item\label{th:leftnoe} $\Lambda$ is left noetherian.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\ref{th:leftnoe}. Since $\Lambda$ has a finite filtration...\par
\ref{th:radnil}. Let $I$ be an ideal in $\Lambda$...\par
\ref{th:finsim}. If for a $\Lambda$-module $A$ we have...
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `enumitem` package one can define a customized list-like environment; in the following example the `thmclaim` environment works as an `enumerate` environment but using boldfaced labels; inside the `proof` environment, a `description` environment was used to refer to the claims (thus keeping consistent use of boldfaced type):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newlist{thmclaim}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmclaim,1]{label=\normalfont\textbf{\arabic*.}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
For a left artin ring $\Lambda$ we have the following.
\begin{thmclaim}
\item\label{th:radnil} The radical of $\Lambda$ is nilpotent.
\item\label{th:finsim} There is only a finite number of nonisomorphic simple $\Lambda$-modules.
\item\label{th:leftnoe} $\Lambda$ is left noetherian.
\end{thmclaim}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\begin{description}
\item[\ref{th:leftnoe}] Since $\Lambda$ has a finite filtration...\par
\item[\ref{th:radnil}] Let $I$ be an ideal in $\Lambda$...\par
\item[\ref{th:finsim}] If for a $\Lambda$-module $A$ we have...
\end{description}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a variation using alphabetical characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newlist{thmclaim}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmclaim,1]{label=\normalfont\textbf{(\alph*)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
For a left artin ring $\Lambda$ we have the following.
\begin{thmclaim}
\item\label{th:radnil} The radical of $\Lambda$ is nilpotent.
\item\label{th:finsim} There is only a finite number of nonisomorphic simple $\Lambda$-modules.
\item\label{th:leftnoe} $\Lambda$ is left noetherian.
\end{thmclaim}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\begin{description}
\item[\ref{th:leftnoe}] Since $\Lambda$ has a finite filtration...\par
\item[\ref{th:radnil}] Let $I$ be an ideal in $\Lambda$...\par
\item[\ref{th:finsim}] If for a $\Lambda$-module $A$ we have...
\end{description}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And yet another variation changing also the `ref` key to automatically add "Proof of claim " (this can be redundant):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newlist{thmclaim}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmclaim,1]{label=\normalfont\textbf{\arabic*.},ref=Proof of claim~\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
For a left artin ring $\Lambda$ we have the following.
\begin{thmclaim}
\item\label{th:radnil} The radical of $\Lambda$ is nilpotent.
\item\label{th:finsim} There is only a finite number of nonisomorphic simple $\Lambda$-modules.
\item\label{th:leftnoe} $\Lambda$ is left noetherian.
\end{thmclaim}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\begin{description}
\item[\ref{th:leftnoe}] Since $\Lambda$ has a finite filtration...\par
\item[\ref{th:radnil}] Let $I$ be an ideal in $\Lambda$...\par
\item[\ref{th:finsim}] If for a $\Lambda$-module $A$ we have...
\end{description}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But should I use a description environment inside the proof? Or just manually write labels as yours?

Comment: A `description` environment? No need. Since you are using a `proof` environment, there's no need to repeat "Proof of claim 1", "Proof of claim 2"; it would be redundant; moreover, using the approach suggested by toheca you would be doing the numbering manually and this is clearly error-prone.

Comment: But what's about \begin{description}\item[3.] ...? Wouldn't it better than just "3."?

Comment: @porton Why would it be better? You're manually doing the numbering and that can cause errors if later you decide to modify the order of the claims in the theorem.

Comment: Errors with renumbering is rather unlikely, as the list are short and the document is edited by me only without collaborators. I am asking would to use description environment for FORMATTING not numbering.

Comment: @porton No need to use uppercase; I can read in lowercase too. What exactly would you use `description` for? Do you want to change numbers for letters or something like that?

Comment: No, I consider to use description environment instead of plain "3." thingy to change the formatting (not to change the numbering).

Comment: @porton please see my updated answer.

Comment: @porton The numbers you place at the start already show clearly what you're doing. A long list, with its indented margin easily makes for a poor page; the same is true for long lists, of course: lists are better to consist of short and catching items. How short? There's of course no rule. Paraphrasing St. Augustine: "When is a list too long? When I see one, I know; if I have to explain why, I don't know any more." `;-)`